# How to write my own printer driver for a printer that is no longer supported by manufacturer?

Tags: macos, printing, driver, macos-catalina

The question pretty much says it all. I basically want to create a driver that is compatible with my current MacOS (Catalina). The issue I'm facing is that my printer (with scanner) currently will only scan pages and print them out. I'd like to be able to use my scanner to save an image of a scanned document.

I'm honestly not sure if writing a driver is the best way to do this but the manufacturer (Canon) no longer has drivers for this old scanner. But it works just as well as the day we got it so I *REALLY* don't want to have to toss this one out and buy a new one.

UPDATE: currently stuck with the following:

```
rabdelazin@rabdelazim Downloads % device=$(sane-find-scanner | awk '/Canon/{print $NF}')
rabdelazin@rabdelazim Downloads % echo $device                                          
libusb:020:029
rabdelazin@rabdelazim Downloads % scanimage --device Canon:$device -x 210 -y 297 --mode color --resolution 240 --format=tiff --depth 8 > ~/Downloads/scan.tiff       
scanimage: open of device Canon:libusb:020:029 failed: Operation not supported
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what Canon model?

Comment: Canon Pixma MP140

Comment: That device is supported by the SANE project http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html I have an EPSON scanner and installed `libusb` and `sane-backends` with **homebrew** and made a simple-ish script to scan. You could also get a Raspberry Pi and attach your Canon to that and run the SANE daemon that your Mac could likely talk to. I'll try and find my code tomorrow if the concept sounds interesting to you.

Comment: yes definitely interested. This sounds like what i'm looking for. Would prefer not to buy any additional hardware to get this working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a LOT of trial and error, I've finally come up with a solution.

TL;DR: I made a print server out of a raspberry-pi and installed cups and set the printer to be shared through the server. Works like a charm!

It took quite a bit of investigation but as part of reviving an old laptop, I got it running by installing Ubuntu 20.04. Just for kicks I decided to try and print something from the laptop. I had to install CUPS and maybe a few other packages but it worked. That got me thinking that I should just make a print server that knows how to talk to the printer so all the other machines can come and go but my printer *should* still work.

Answer (score 1):

I have an EPSON Perfection 4990 Photo on **macOS**, so I cannot give you full code and examples for your Canon but it may get you started. I spend my life in Terminal rather than using GUIs for anything so I just scan the full area of the platten at full resolution and do whatever I need later with **ImageMagick** or Photoshop if necessary.

So, to get it going I installed **homebrew** from [here](https://brew.sh). Then I installed some packages:

```
brew install libusb
brew install sane-backends
```

Then I can find my scanner with:

```
sane-find-scanner
```

**Sample Output**

```
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x012a [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:003:002
```

Now you need the last word on that line, the `libusb:003:002` part, with my EPSON, I use:

```
sane-find-scanner | awk '/EPSON/{print $NF}'
```

You will need to see what you get, and adapt slightly.

**SampleOutput**

```
libusb:003:002
```

So, in order to scan, I capture that in a `bash` variable called `device` and do this:

```
device=$(sane-find-scanner | awk '/EPSON/{print $NF}')

scanimage --device epson:$device -x 210 -y 297 --mode color --resolution 240 --format=tiff --depth 8 > ~/Desktop/scan.tif
```

I put the whole lot in a `bash` script called `scan` like this:

```
#/bin/bash

TMP="$HOME/Desktop/scan.tif"

# Find libusb device name
device=$(sane-find-scanner | awk '/EPSON|HP/{print $NF}')
if [ -z $device ]; then
   echo ERROR: Unable to find libusb device
   exit 1
fi
echo Found scanner at: $device

# Now scan full-size, colour, hi res
scanimage --device epson:$device -x 210 -y 297 --mode color --resolution 240 --format=tiff --depth 8 > "$TMP"

# Check we got a file
if [ ! -s "$TMP" ]; then
   echo ERROR: Empty scan
   exit 1
fi
```

My script has some further, optional, **ImageMagick** stuff at the end to create a Web-usable JPEG, if you add this you will need to do:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Then add this to the script above:

```
# Copy the file to User's Desktop and number nicely...
# ... save as hi-res 16-bit TIF
# ... and medium res, medium quality JPG for web use
cd ~/Desktop
i=0
while :; do
   base=$(printf "scan-%03d" $i)
   if [ ! -f "${base}.jpg" ]; then
      cp "$TMP" "${base}.tif"
      convert "$TMP" -resize 2000x2000 -quality 85% "${base}.jpg"
      break
   fi
   ((i++))
done
```

Here are a couple of resources I found helpful when working it all out. You can debug the `scanimage` program with:

```
SANE_DEBUG_SNAPSCAN=128 scanimage -L
```

[This resource](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/sane-epson2.5.html) was useful.

You can get help like this:

```
scanimage --help -d epson
```

---

Note that you may also be able to use a Raspberry Pi or similar small, low-cost Linux machine as a *"scanner server"*. Basically you would attach your scanner via USB to the Raspberry Pi and run SANE on the Raspberry Pi. Once you get it working, you could run `saned` which is a daemon service, on the Raspberry Pi, that listens on the network for other devices (such as your Mac) making requests to scan. It does the scan, using its Linux SANE drivers and delivers the image back over the Ethernet to the Mac (or other) client. I know you dislike this option, but there may be future readers...

**Keywords**: macOS, OSX, scan, scanner, scanning, EPSON, Canon, HP, libusb, SANE, sane-backends

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I changed the command to capitalize the name of the device but now I get this: `scanimage: open of device Canon:libusb:020:021 failed: Operation not supported` I'll post the command in the next comment.

Comment: command generating the "not supported error": `scanimage --device Canon:$device -x 210 -y 297 --mode color --resolution 240 --format=tiff --depth 8 > ~/Downloads/scan.tiff`

Comment: Relevant output of `scanimage` command is as follows: `found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x172b [MP140 series]) at libusb:020:029`